# UIWebView scalesPageToFit is overriding the font size specified

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uiwebview, mathml

Im rendering normal text along with MathML content in a UIWebview, scalesPageToFit property enabled and and my syntax of displaying data is 
startHtml and endHtml is as below,

```
startHTML=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"<html><Head><Meta Content-Type=\"text/mathml\"/>\
               <script type=\"text/javascript\" src=\"%@?config=MML_HTMLorMML-full\"></script>\
               </head>\
               <body style=\'padding:25px 15px 15px 25px\'>\
               <font face='Calibri' size='28'>",scriptFilePath];

endHtml=@"</font></body></html>";
```

inside startHtml string i'm mentioning font style and its weight but whatever the actual font size im mentioning here is not getting reflected since webviews scalesPageToFit is overriding it, if i disable scalesPageToFit property alignment and MathMl rendering is getting messed up.

How to maintain custom font size with scalesPageToFit property enabled?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use pixel values for your font size.  I think percent would probably be best.